# Schwarz's lemma question.

Tags: complex-analysis

The next question is from Conway's book first volume page 132:

"Suppose $|f(z)|\leq 1 \ for \ |z|<1$ and $f$ is analytic. By considering the function:
$g:D \rightarrow D$ defined by: 
$$g(z)=\frac{f(z)-a}{1-\bar{a}f(z)}$$
where $a=f(0)$, prove that:

$$\frac{|f(0)|-|z|}{1+|f(0)||z|}\leq |f(z)| \leq \frac{|f(0)|+|z|}{1-|f(0)||z|}$$
for $|z|<1$.

I understnad that I need to show that the assumptions of Schwarz's lemma indeed follow on $g$, i see that $g(0)=0$, but I can't see why $|g(z)| \leq 1 \ for \ |z|<1$, I don't seem to be able to show that indeed this is the case.

Perhaps I need to use another theorem in this section of Schwarz lemma in conway's book.

Comment: Were the automorphisms of (the sphere, the plane, and) the unit disk already treated? $$T\colon w \mapsto \frac{w-a}{1-\overline{a}w}$$ is, for $\lvert a\rvert < 1$, an automorphism of the unit disk.

Comment: The trick is just to apply Schwarz' lemma to $g$, then express $f(z)$ in terms of $g(z)$ and use the triangle inequality.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But I am finding it difficult to show that $|g(z)|\leq 1 \ for \ |z|<1$

Answer (score 0):

See exercises 9 and 10 in Chapter 3, Section 3.